# Error: expected 'asm' before long

Tags: c, makefile, linux-kernel, ubuntu-12.04, asmx

Hey guys so I'm trying to make a system call in ubuntu 12.04.1. I'm running into an issue compiling my hello.c file

```
    #include <linux/kernel.h>
    asmlinkage long sys_hello(void) {
    printk("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I believe the issue is in my Makefile but I'm still a beginner in writing Makefiles.

```
hello.o: hello.c
        gcc -c -o hello.o hello.c
obj-y := hello.o
```

I know I have to add the obj-y := hello.o part so it can compile and be included in the kernel. When I run make I get this error:

```
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'long'
```

I'm not totally sure what to do and I'm stuck. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try including `<linux/linkage.h>`?

Comment: Now I receive a fatal error: linux/linkage.h: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

You need the kernel sources.  will be there: https://www.kernel.org/

Guide if you don't have one: http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html